Sushiswap Router contract address on the Sepolia public testnet
Can anyone help me find the Sushiswap Router contract address on the Sepolia public testnet? I’ve already located the Uniswap Router address but am having trouble finding the one for Sushiswap.

This question is similar to: Sushiswap Router Contract Address on Sepolia Public Testnet?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
